# sklearn: silhouette score different for same clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I modified the [Cluster comparison](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html) script to compute [`silhouette_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) on the clustering output.

I added this line:

```
sil = silhouette_score(X, y_pred, metric='euclidean') if len(np.unique(y_pred)) > 1 else float('NaN')
```

and modified the `plt.text()` line for showing the `sil` value in the subplot:

```
txt = 'sil={:.3f}\n{:.2f}s'.format(sil,(t1 - t0))
plt.text(.99, .01, txt, transform=plt.gca().transAxes, size=15, horizontalalignment='right')
```

This is what I get:

[image: 1]

Look at 3rd row, for columns MeanShoft and DBSCAN. Clustering is the same, but silhouette score is significantly lower for DBSCAN. How come?

<sub>Since this question is not about a programming error, shall this be moved to stats?</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the clusterings aren't the same. If you look *very* closely at the DBSCAN plot, you'll see that there is an outlier at the bottom left of the blue cluster that is not assigned to any cluster -- it appears as a black point.

Note that the silhouette score assumes that all points are assigned to a cluster, so it may not give the answer you'd expect. In this case, the single point not assigned to any cluster is enough to make a significant difference in the silhouette scores.

Comment: Demonstrates that such evaluation measures are based on assumptions that may not hold for a clustering result (e.g. noise) and cannot be used to judge the quality of results that don't follow these assumptions. (In particular, I don't think the DBSCAN result is the worst of the pack.)

Comment: @jme you were right, it turned out there was a singleton cluster. That negatively affected the silhouette score for DBSCAN

Comment: @Anony-Mousse yes, it seems the silhouette score is not robust to noise. I added a preprocessing step in which I filter clusters with less than M elements (M typically small, i.e. 5~20). Anyway its usefulness depends highly on the metric used. The DBSCAN algorithm has the advantage over other algorithms that is not distance based, but then evaluating its score using an internal evaluation (silhouette score) that uses a metric (euclidean) kind of defeats its purpose and is likely to score it negatively.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I'm planning to use multiple metrics with silhouette score and then use rank aggregation to get a ranking based on multiple metrics. I hope that would alleviate this problem

Comment: @mescalinum DBSCAN *is* distance based, and removing noise or small clusters will distort the results just as much.

Comment: DBSCAN is density based